# Integral $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos x + c}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Could you help to find the answer of this integral?

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos x + c}}$$

Does it have a solution? if not, how to prove it?
Thank you,

Comment: https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=1%2Fsqrt%28cosx%2Bc%29, just click "Go!" and "Show steps".

Comment: You should take the to learn [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) The mark-up system for this site it avoids any confusion regarding what the equation actually is.

Comment: thank you ! really usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is given by:

$${\frac {2}{c-1}J^{-1}\left( x/2,{\frac {\sqrt {2}}{\sqrt {c
+1}}} \right) }
$$

in which

$$J^{-1}(\phi,k)=\int_{0}^{\phi}\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 u}}.$$

Hence, the integral does not seem to have a simple closed form solution.

Comment: Is there a name for this special function? It looks familiar. Edit: It's an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind)

Answer (score 0):

In a sense it does have a solution, $2F(\frac{x+c}{2}|2)+const$. The function $F$ is an elliptic integral of first kind, which is **defined** as a solution to this kind of integrals, and cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Proving ideas are discussed in [How can you prove that a function has no closed form integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)